# Why do I get C# raw socket error?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm writing this code toget data packets from a client:

```
byte[] input = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("46.105.248.69"), 1369));
s.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, input, null);
int bytes;
bytes = s.Receive(buffer);
while (bytes > 0)
{
    label1.Text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
    bytes = s.Receive(buffer);
}
```

but when I run this code, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Error in this line:

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to get data through the Socket, if so I suggest, have a quick look to [Asynchronous Server Socket Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: are you logged in as user or administrator?

Comment: Can you telnet like telnet 46.105.248.69 1369 using command prompt?